# Converting a sparse matrix into a smaller full matrix

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have

```
    A = [3 0 2; ...
         0 0 1; ...
         1 1 0]
    A = sparse(A);
```

The output of which is below:

```
    ans =

   (1,1)        3
   (3,1)        1
   (3,2)        1
   (1,3)        2
   (2,3)        1
```

Question: is there an easy command to generate the following vector?

```
   B = [1 1 3;3 1 1; 3 2 1; 1 3 2;2 3 1]

    ans =

         1     1     3
         3     1     1
         3     2     1
         1     3     2
         2     3     1
```

Comment: What is relation between A and B? What is you expect to see as output from 'easy command'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
[ ii jj aij ] = find( A );
B = [ii(:) jj(:) aij(:)];
```

Comment: You do not need the second line if you use `[B(:,1) B(:,2) B(:,3)] = find( A );`